# Rotate resets to 0deg on Scaling CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I am facing a problem in doing **Rotate** and **Scale** operations on image.

There are some similar questions asked on stackOverflow and I too have referred them but no success. So I am putting this up.

I have added a snippet where there are 3 buttons and an image.

The **Rotate** and **+** & **-** works pretty well but when you Zoom(**+** or **-**) it after the rotate then it would RESET the rotate to how it was initially. And similarly the Rotate operations reduces the scale to 1.

I also tried rotating the container-div of image which worked fine but it created a problem in **Drag** operations so couldn't use that idea too..

So is there any way to stop SCALE to not to RESET Rotate ??

Any help is appreciated.

```js
var curScale = 1;
var zoomFactor = 1.2;
var rotateAngle = 0;

// ZOOMING
function zoomIn(){
 curScale *= zoomFactor;
 $("#previewImg").css({"transform":'scale('+curScale+')'})
}
function zoomOut(){
 curScale /= zoomFactor;
 $("#previewImg").css({"transform":'scale('+curScale+')'})
}




// ROTATION
function doRotate(){
 rotateAngle += 90;
 $("#previewImg").css("transform","rotate("+rotateAngle+"deg)");
}
```

```css
#previewImg{
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:15%;
  left:15%;
}

button{
  position:fixed;
  top:10;
  margin-left:20px;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick='zoomIn()' style="left:5px">+</button>
<button onClick='zoomOut()' style="left:30px">-</button>
<button onClick='doRotate()' style="left:60px">Rotate</button>
<div>
  
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg" id='previewImg'>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var curScale = 1;
var zoomFactor = 1.2;
var rotateAngle = 0;

// ZOOMING
function zoomIn() {
  curScale *= zoomFactor;
  $('#previewImg').css({
    'transform': 'scale(' + curScale + ') rotate(' + rotateAngle + 'deg)'
  });
}

function zoomOut() {
  curScale /= zoomFactor;
  $('#previewImg').css({
    'transform': 'scale(' + curScale + ') rotate(' + rotateAngle + 'deg)'
  });
}

// ROTATION
function doRotate() {
  rotateAngle += 90;
  $('#previewImg').css({
    'transform': 'scale(' + curScale + ') rotate(' + rotateAngle + 'deg)'
  });
}
```

```css
#previewImg {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10;
  margin-left: 20px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick='zoomIn()' style="left:5px">+</button>
<button onClick='zoomOut()' style="left:30px">-</button>
<button onClick='doRotate()' style="left:60px">Rotate</button>
<div>

  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg" id='previewImg'>


</div>
```

Sorry am late.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is, but it requires a slight change in your code.

You need to set the change you want and then apply the transformation, taking into account both of the properties:

```js
var curScale = 1;
var zoomFactor = 1.2;
var rotateAngle = 0;

// ZOOMING
function zoomIn() {
  curScale *= zoomFactor;
  applyTransformation();
}

function zoomOut() {
  curScale /= zoomFactor;
  applyTransformation();
}

// ROTATION
function doRotate() {
  rotateAngle += 90;
  applyTransformation();
}

function applyTransformation() {
  $('#previewImg').css({
    'transform': 'scale(' + curScale + ') rotate(' + rotateAngle + 'deg)'
  })
}
```

```css
#previewImg {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10;
  margin-left: 20px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick='zoomIn()' style="left:5px">+</button>
<button onClick='zoomOut()' style="left:30px">-</button>
<button onClick='doRotate()' style="left:60px">Rotate</button>
<div>

  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg" id='previewImg'>


</div>
```